# Why do I get gibberish text at the end of a received package?

Tags: c, visual-studio, client-server, esp8266, lidar

I'm making a LiDAR project for university but I got stuck a little bit. I am sending a package which includes the exact position of the motor and the distance read from the distance sensor through WiFi and the package should look like this "position/distance". I made a client program in Visual Studio but when I receive the package I have iiiiii at the end of the message and the packages are not coming through in the right order. I am gonna put the code here and if you have any idea of what I am missing I would appreciate it a lot.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "winsock2.h"

#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE* file;

    file = fopen("package.txt", "w");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error openning the file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int iResult;

    WSADATA wsaData;

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
        printf("Error WSAStartup\n");

    SOCKET ClientSocket;
    ClientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Error initializing socket with the next error code: %ld\n",
            WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    int Port = 13000;
    char IP[14] = "192.168.0.105";
    sockaddr_in ServerAddr;
    int AddrLen = sizeof(ServerAddr);
    ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);
    ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);

    if (connect(ClientSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&ServerAddr, AddrLen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Error connecting with the next error code: %ld\n",
            WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        printf("Sikeres kapcsolodas\n");
    }

    char message[15];
    int receiving = 0;
    while (receiving != SOCKET_ERROR) {
        receiving = recv(ClientSocket, message, sizeof(message), 0);
        fprintf(file, "%s\n", message);
        printf("%i, %i\n", receiving, sizeof(message));
    }
    
    if (receiving == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Error at receiving the message\n");
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

The message that I get looks like this:

0.00/176.00ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
0.75/180.003.75ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
/179.008.63/179ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
.009.008.63/179ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
14.06/179.0019.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
13/178.00.0019.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
24.19/178.0019.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
29.44/179.0019.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
35.06/178.0019.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
39.94/180.0045.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
19/178.00.0045.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
50.44/180.0045.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
55.69/179.0061.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
50/179.00.0061.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
66.19/180.0072.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
38/178.00.0072.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
77.63/178.0083.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
25/178.00.0083.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
88.13/178.0093.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
56/176.00.0093.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
99.19/177.0093.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
104.44/177.0011ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
0.25/176.000011ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
115.31/177.0011ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
121.13/177.0011ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
126.75/173.0013ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
2.19/176.00136.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
88/176.0000136.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
142.69/176.0014ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
8.31/177.000014ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
153.75/177.0014ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
159.38/174.0016ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
5.38/173.000016ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
170.63/174.0017ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
5.88/169.000017ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
181.13/169.0018ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
7.13/169.000018ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
192.56/167.0019ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
8.38/170.000019ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
203.81/168.0019ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
209.25/166.0021ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
4.88/165.000021ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
220.69/168.0021ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
226.13/167.0023ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
1.94/167.000023ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
237.56/167.0024ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
3.38/166.000024ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
248.81/169.0025ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
4.25/169.00259.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
88/170.00265.69ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
/170.00271.31/1ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
69.0000271.31/1ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
277.50/170.0028ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ

Note: it should look like ex. 241.00/32.00, position expressed in degree and distance in mm.

Comment: I would try clearing the message buffer before passing it to recv in the while loop: while (receiving != SOCKET_ERROR) {
memset( message, 0, sizeof(message));

Comment: I tried this but I still don't know why I get the bytes from the next message too. The first two are ok but from there on the second 2 bytes from the next message concatenates to the message and gets sent earlier than it should have.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
receiving = recv(ClientSocket, message, sizeof(message), 0);
```

`receiving` is set to the number of bytes actually received.
It is not necessarily the size of the buffer you pass in (in your case it is a few bytes less).

But when you dump it th the file in this line:

```
fprintf(file, "%s\n", message);
```

You ignore the number of bytes received.
Using with `fprintf` with "%s" requires a zero terminated array of characters, and `resv` does not add the zero termination.

You can solve this issue by adding this line before the `fprintf`:

```
message[receiving] = '\0';
```

Another issue is the maximum number of bytes `recv` is allowed to fill.
Since we want to keep one byte for the zero termination, the call to `recv` should be:

```
receiving = recv(ClientSocket, message, sizeof(message)-1, 0);
```

I.e. allow receive fill only `sizeof(message)-1` bytes and keep one for the zero termination.

Comment: This was the problem to the gibberish characters from the end but I still get characters from the next message. And I don't know why. Maybe the problem is with the other code from the ESP8266 ?

Comment: The tcp/ip stack does not correlate messages to calls of `recv`. If you send with high enough speed, you can get them concatenated (you will get chunks of max size of sizeof(message)-1, but the messages might be concatenated). In order to handle this situation you must have another layer that builds the messages. You'd better have a header for the messages, where you can put the message size and parse accordingly.

Comment: You can also use `fprintf(file, "%.*s\n", receiving, message)` to specify the (maximum) number of bytes to copy from message.  This does not require you to add the null byte at the end of the message (though there may well be other reasons for adding that byte — byte arrays are not so easily handled in C).